# Usar min() y max() de un array con php

Tags: php

El siguiente ejemplo me guarda en la variable **$min** el numero mas chico de la lista que esta en el array

```
$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10); 
$min=min($array); 
echo"$min";
```

Mi pregunta: Lo que yo necesito es que me busque el numero mas chico despues del 1 o sea que me indique la variable **$min** que el numero mas chico es el 1 y no el 0 como es el caso anterior. espero que se entienda.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php) puedes obtener un array que excluya todos los elementos menores a 1. Después, solo usas [min](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.min.php) con ese array.

```
$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10); 
$min = min(array_filter($array, function($item) {
    return $item > 0;
}));
echo $min;
```

Comment: Muy amable @RockoDev , funciona de maravilla. Saludos.

Comment: Si te funcionó, puedes marcar esta respuesta como la solución. Saludos.